# Separate files in Git

Tags: git, heroku, branch

I'm trying to keep my **static files in a separate branch** so that I can keep them from merging into my master brach (on Heroku, your application's slug needs to stay small). I don't want to ignore my static files, because I want to keep them inside my "devel" branch.

Ideally I'd like to keep test.db blank and my entire public folder blank in the master branch.

So, can I create an 'overlay' onto a branch? Can I prevent certain files/directories from merging into my master branch?

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks for the spellcheck.

Comment: Note: this is one solution, but others may propose some other organization to achieve the same result.

Comment: As I'd suspect. I'd certainly be interested in hearing other interesting solutions, even just for my own/other's edification.

Comment: Is it appropriate to mention that in the question – should I maybe change the title to 'How would you separate files in Git'?

Comment: If you set a `.gitattribute` in the *parent* directory of public, with the pattern `public/*`, that should be enough.

Comment: That's what I figured, but git seems to ignore it. It also ignored .gitattribute -- I needed to make it .gitattributes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could define those same static files on your master branch but:

- empty
- witw a gitattributes files specifying you [always want to keep your local version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp) (i.e. empty) when merging those files

Since that .gitattribute would not be define on other branches, the merge of those files would proceed normally.

---

The idea is to define a .gitattributes file in the directory of those static files on the master branch with the following content:

```
myStaticFile1 merge=keepMine
myStaticFile2 merge=keepMine
myStaticFile3 merge=keepMine
```

Those three files will always keep their local content (which is empty on master) when merging to master.

You will have to define a merge driver (here called "keepmine"). See the linked question for that script.

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail? I've not used attributes before and the link isn't 100% straightforward.

Comment: Also, I don't seem to be able to define wildcards, I tried public/* merge=keepMine, which didn't work. I also tried removing the directory and touching it, making a file, but Git complains and makes another version of public on merge.

Answer (score 0):

Add the files to .gitignore in master. When you checkout devel, .gitignore will change and won't ignore them anymore. (Note that if you run `git clean -x`, the files will be overwritten.)