# Git merge from a specific folder only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, merge, branch, directory

I've created a rails website for client X. I now have a client, Y, who wants a website that does the exact same thing as client X, but with a different skin.

I made a git branch from clientXcode and called it clientYcode. I then did all the changes to the views to make it look different, and lala, the same website with a different skin.

Now here's what I don't understand about git: I've made many changes to clientXcode in the views, models, and controllers; and now I want to merge those changes into clientYcode, excluding any view changes. Since views, models, and controllers each have their own folder in rails I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```
git merge client_x_code 'app/controllers/*', 'app/models/*'
```

QUESTION 1: Is something like that possible with git? If so, how would I do it?

QUESTION 2: Was branching the best solution to make a copy of my project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I found the easiest solution to my problem...

```
git checkout clientYcode
git checkout clientXcode "app/controllers/"
git checkout clientXcode "app/models/"
```

And that does what I want!

Comment: But that is only temporary in your workarea, and next time you switch branches you will have to repeat all that.

Comment: well I of course then do a commit to save the changes in my current branch

Comment: Thats nice! Also see http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/ for a complete writeup!

Comment: Can you also add policies? Like `-X ours`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest course of action is to merge everything, except the content of the directory you want to keep.
You can do that by adding a merge driver in that directory, as the [How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp) question details.

With that merge driver in place, Branching is a good solution in this case.

---

Extract:

> We have a `.gitattributes` file defined in the `dirWithCopyMerge` directory (defined only in the branch where the merge will occurs: `myBranch`), and we have a `.git\config` file which now contains a merge driver.

```
[merge "keepMine"]
        name = always keep mine during merge
        driver = keepMine.sh %O %A %B
```

Comment: @DotNetWise you can see `keepMine.sh` defined and used (on Windows) in http://stackoverflow.com/a/930495/6309

Comment: Thanks. Just for the record, it could simply be `keepMine.bat` located in your `PATH` folders