# Tell git not to merge binary files but to choose

Tags: git, merge, binaryfiles, git-merge

When the binary files, swfs, jars and flvs are changed locally, and I try to pull in changes, git tries to merge them and reports conflict.

And then, I branch to a temporary branch, and commit the local changed binary files, and merge them back after the pull with recursive theirs strategy. -- Too much work.

Is there a way to tell git, not to attempt merging binary files and ask me which one of these versions to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set up a merge drive in a `.gitattributes` file (only for a given subtree, only for some file types)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676183/git-merge-from-a-specific-folder-only/1676235#1676235) for instance (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408748/how-to-handle-gitting-of-binaries-e-g-mo-files/2408931#2408931)).

```
# choose the name of the merge driver to be use for all jar files
echo *.jar merge=keepTheir > dirWithJarFiles\.gitattributes
```

Declare your merge driver in the config of the Git repo:

```
git config merge.keepTheir.name "always keep their during merge"
git config merge.keepTheir.driver "keepTheir.sh %O %A %B"
```

or

```
git config merge.keepMine.name "always keep mine during merge"
git config merge.keepMine.driver "keepMine.sh %O %A %B"
[merge "keepMine"]
        name = always keep mine during merge
        driver = keepMine.sh %O %A %B
```

The example I give don't ask you for a choice but will always keep "mine" (or "yours") version when merging.
But you could adapt the script executed by this merge driver to ask you a question, and then apply your choice to all merges.