# Git: Merge old commit into current head version

Tags: git, merge

Got a file that has two commits of interest, both on the `Master` branch, both only modifying a single file `foo`: a previous commit `AA`, and the current version in `HEAD`. I would like to merge the two versions of the file, keeping bits of both, into `HEAD` on `Master`.

I did the simplest thing that I thought would work:

```
git checkout -b merge-purgatory AA
git commit -m "pulled foo back from previous commit for merging into HEAD."
git checkout master
git merge merge-purgatory
```

Which simply overwrites the current `HEAD` version of `foo` with `AA` version.
Tried the more verbose `git checkout -m` as well, same result: a dumb overwrite.

How do I force git to treat the `AA` version of `foo` as a conflicting merge with the current `HEAD` version?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If git's merge isn't doing what you want, you could do the following instead:

1. Make sure that there are no uncommitted changes in the file `foo`, e.g. by making sure that `git status` is clean.
2. Overwrite `foo` with the version from `AA` using: `git show AA:foo > foo`
3. Selectively stage only the changes from `foo` that you want with: `git add -p foo`
4. Discard all the other changes to `foo` with `git checkout -- foo`
5. Commit the staged changes: `git commit`

Alternatively, if you'd rather use a graphical diff tool (such as `meld`), you could just do:

```
git show AA:foo > old-foo
meld old-foo foo
```

Comment: So basically, just bypass git's knowledge of the previous commit and use a manual merge/mergetool. Was hoping for a more cromulent behavior from git, but this is so simple that I used it successfully and just did a bit of clean-up afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I get rid of it using:

`git checkout -f b855a13754fabf5cef6ff93ab00558608a839377 -- .`

which forces the changes of the commit id into my current branch (master), then I created a new branch (`checkout -b`) from these applied changes and created a merge request from the latter.

*None of the above worked for me :-(*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I have used this multiple times to reset the state of a branch to re-apply changes as new changes, when re-introducing them in a PR does not work

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers do not keep the story of the change, so the fact that you used a previous commit to generate the new commit.
The following procedure will keep this story.

```
git checkout -b merge-purgatory AA
```

here you need to slightly modify your file, for example you can add an empty line. Then

```
git commit "pulled foo back from previous commit for merging into HEAD."
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit merge-purgatory
```

In this way the merge will fail and then all you need to do is to solve the conflict. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
git merge --no-commit merge-purgatory
```

would at least give you the opportunity to review:change the merge before committing it.
See also techniques proposed in "[How do you merge selective files with git-merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-do-you-merge-selective-files-with-git-merge)", based on cherry-picking or checkout.

---

Regarding forcing the manual merge, you could declare in a [`.gitatributes` file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitattributes), for that specific file, a **merge policy set to unset**.

> Performing a three-way merge
>
> merge
>
> ```
> The attribute merge affects how three versions of a file is merged when a file-level merge is necessary during git merge, and other commands such as git revert and git cherry-pick.
> ```

```
Unset
```

> Take the version from the current branch as the tentative merge result, and declare that the merge has conflicts. This is suitable for binary files that does not have a well-defined merge semantics.

Comment: And, in any case, "Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested" doesn't quite answer my question: how to prevent the "Automatic merge" from happening, and instead treat the two versions as conflicting (they are, overwriting each other's lines) and requiring a manual merge?

Comment: @Noel: sorry, I zapped the manual merge part. I have edited my answer.

Comment: thanks! But, hrm: `echo "* -merge" >> .git/info/attributes` and then `git merge --no-commit merge-purgatory` still results in "Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested".

Comment: @Noel that looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122056/how-to-get-3-way-merge-in-git-on-non-conflict-merges and should have worked. Did you set the policy to unset, with a `/path/to/your/file merge=unset` line?

Comment: ah, didn't understand that I needed both (just tried them individually). Put both in .git/info/attributes, then `git merge --no-commit merge-purgatory` resulted in
"Auto-merging search/src/main/webapp/js/search.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in search/src/main/webapp/js/search.js
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result." Which is precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: However, given the dead-simple approach of @Mark Longair, I would rather not muck about with adding (& afterwards removing) lines from my .git folder just for a case like this.