# User related files in IntelliJ IDEA project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We have a small team using IntelliJ IDEA as Java IDE and manage our source code with git. The IDEA project was created as directory based format. I found some files under `.idea` are user related.

Is there a complete list of user-related files that I can filter out with `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please [check the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186).

I also recommend checking other files you are going to share for the sensitive information. For example, new Android artifacts in IntelliJ IDEA 12 can contain keystore passwords (in encrypted form, but could be decrypted).

Your question is also a duplicate of these:

- [What to gitignore from the .idea folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968531/what-to-gitignore-from-the-idea-folder)
- [Intellij Idea 9/10, what folders to check into (or not check into) source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041154/intellij-idea-9-10-what-folders-to-check-into-or-not-check-into-source-contro)
- [How to deal with IntelliJ IDEA project files under Git source control constantly changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060727/how-to-deal-with-intellij-idea-project-files-under-git-source-control-constantly)