# How does PyCharm know the project type of a cloned Git repository

Tags: git, github, pycharm

How does PyCharm know / configures the project type when Pycharm clones a Git or Github repository.

When I create a new PyCharm project, I configure a project type.

Example PyCharm project types: Google App Engine project, Django project.

**Update:**

This [Github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python) does not contain any project settings. See VonC answer below.
Cloning it with Pycharm works fine. I do not use standard paths for the Python interpreter and the App Engine SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the GitHub repo include project settings file (as it is recommended in "[How to deal with IntelliJ IDEA project files under Git source control constantly changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18839911/6309)")

- `.ipr` file based format
- `.idea/` directory based format

If those files are in the Git repo, PyCharm would have no problem configuring the project based on the settings included in said files.

Comment: Now I have path mismatches (Pyhon and App Engine SDK path in the PyCharm project settings) when I clone a Git remote which includes .idea files. But I do not have this problem at all, when using Github. See Update in the question.

Comment: @voscausa then PyCharm must infer the nature of the project when it is imported, and generate on-the-fly default project settings.

Comment: I quessed and tried: the naming of the remote GIT repository does the trick