# Git Exclude a file from the merge

Tags: git, netbeans, tortoisegit

I want to merge my branch 'S' to another branch 'T', but there's a file in my branch that I want to be excluded from the merge for my own reasons, and I want the history of my changes on that file to be removed as well. Is there's a way that I could do that using Netbeans's Git, or Tortoise, or whatever. I'm new to this so hopefully you might help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can (or should) avoid the command line for those kind of operation.

If you really need to remove the full history of a given (sensitive) file, see "[How do I remove sensitive files from git's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history)".

If you only need to avoid that file to be merge in a particular branch, you can setup a merge driver asking to always keep the local version during a merge (as detailed in "[Tell git not to merge binary files but to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920594/tell-git-not-to-merge-binary-files-but-to-choose/2920807#2920807)").