# How to maintain private changes in git?

Tags: git, project

I am using the work flow introduced by [Successful Git branch](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).
I am confused about how to manage changes,like configuration in develop branch.

When I merge from master, to keep working tree clean I stash the changes. If I commit the changes, I should be very careful when I merge back master.

So is there a better way to manage private changes in git?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Do not put private files under source control. For instance, if you need a `config.ini` with private changes for each developer, then create a file `config.ini.template` with example settings in the repository, then each developer should make a copy of it and amend the copy with private settings. The `config.ini` should be added in the `.gitignore`.
2. Add the `config.ini` in the repo and use `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.ini` so that git will ignore any local changes in the file not try to commit the file.
3. Add several config files in the repo for each environment, e.g. `config-robotment.ini`, `config-kan.ini`, `config-produciton.ini` and so on. Then use a command line parameter, or an environment variable, or something similar to allow your application choose which file to use.

And the point is - don't use branches for the configuration, otherwise it will be always painful to branch/merge during development.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I am working on a project that added config file to git and I can't change that. Maybe I can try this on my own project.

Comment: @robotment Use the option 2 then, it doesn't affect repository, just your working copy.

Comment: The config files is already in the repo, and use git update-indexc --assume-unchanged config.ini. If the upstream update config.ini, will local file update?

Comment: @robotment Update from upstream will raise an error, so you will be told to solve the conflict - this is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

For configuration file, the choices are resumed in "[Git: keep specific files unmerged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262171/6309)".

I prefer versioning different value files for each environment (here for each branch), that way I don't have to deal with merge (the value file "`dev.config`" would never be modified in master branch, where the value file "`master.config`" is used)

I also version a template file, in order for a content [filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) to generate the actual config file (which remains private and isn't version) on checkout of the branch:

[image: smudge clean filter driver]

Answer (score 0):

Create and switch to a local branch with a different name, merge upstream master branch when needed.

Comment: What are the command(s) for the OP to `merge upstream branch`? Which branch should they be in, etc. ?

Comment: @linquize If I want to submit, I also have to choose what I really do.