# Git merge all but one file, and that file be a (full) conflicted file

Tags: git, merge, branch

Sorry for the title, it's hard to summarise that in a coherent sentence.

I have seen a lot of others asking for merging all but one or two files, cherry picking usually is the suggestion here. However I'm unsure how to do this, and cannot find similar question.

Basically I have two branches, lets call them `dev` and `refactor`.
I want to merge the `refactor` branch into `dev`, commonly done.

`refactor` contains a few new files and one that is completely different around the main logic (lets call that `file`); I would like to merge the branches, however I want `file` to be conflicted, or at least something similar.

```
// file in <dev>
lots of code
loop
    main logic
lots more code
```

The point of the refactor is to remove the needs for large, highly nested loops. The form of the refactored code is:

```
// file in <refactor>
lots of code
BLANK (where main logic ought to be)
lots more code
```

I would like the whole file to pop into 'conflict mode' or something, so that I can selectively get the *main logic* out of the original and into the new.

This isn't just the one occurrence within the file, there are several, however this is just to give an idea.

Is this possible? or am I going to have to manually copy the code from `dev` into `refactor` before the merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attempt this with a [custom merge driver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10779235/1256452) that just says that the file is conflicted.  However, that only works if both the current branch, and the to-be-merged-in branch, have touched the file since the version stored in the merge base.

---

If you already know which file you want to manually edit after the merge but before committing, I'd just run `git merge --no-commit ...`.  The resulting merge may well be marked "ready to commit", but you can edit it all you like first (and then `git add` the results of editing).  The eventual manual `git commit` you do will be a merge commit, as the merge process leaves files in the `.git` directory to record this.

Whether or not there are any conflicts, while editing, you can `git show HEAD:file` and `git show branch:file` to see those two versions of file `file`.  Dump the results into temporary files if needed.

There's no completely trivial way to see the common-ancestor version, but this two-step method will do it in a Unix-like shell:

```
ancestor=$(git merge-base HEAD branch)
git show ${ancestor}:file
```

(Or, you can simplify this into:

```
git show $(git merge-base HEAD branch):file
```

In either case it's the same method: first we repeat the merge-base computation that `git merge` made, and then we use the selected revision to `show` file `file`.)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I discovered that I didn't need this for the issue at time of writing, however has become needed now.