# Merge only Code Files

Tags: git

How can I just merge the source code files, say `*.h` and `*.cpp`, in Git?

The repository on Github contains the whole solution file including project and compiler data and build executables.

Comment: You shouldn't versionize compiled, or builded files at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a merge driver in a [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file in order to:

- keep your destination version if it is *not* a `.cpp` or `.h` (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2920807/6309))
- <del>git checkout the source into your current branch for the other file (that will trigger a merge for that file</del>, as described in "[Git Tip: How to "Merge" Specific Files from Another Branch](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/)", referenced in "[How do you merge selective files with git-merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355990/6309)")
  There is actually no easy way to trigger a merge that way

Another option is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292109/6309):

```
git merge --no-commit branchSource
# for each non .cpp or .h files:
git checkout branchDestination -- file
```

But that is a bit cumbersome.

---

That being said, a merge should involve the *all* content of a commit, which is why not* versioning elements you don't want to merge is a good idea.
When those elements can be generated at will (build executable), this is twice a good idea (as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082023/merge-only-code-files/14083146#comment19472040_14082023) by [KingCrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421223/kingcrunch)).

Comment: `git checkout` will do a merge?  That doesn't sound right.  Won't `git checkout <branch> -- <paths>` grab the versions of the file on `<branch>`?  I didn't think it performed any merge operation here.

Comment: @jszakmeister true: I have fixed the answer to include a way to merge everything, and restore the destination branch version.