# Collaborative environments using git and xml data

Tags: xml, git, ios5, storyboard

My team develops iOS apps.  We are considering using Storyboards with our next project, however, we are bit concerned with the merging conflicts that we will be inevitably be dealing with in GIT (or any other source control) and the auto-generated xml data behind the scenes in storyboards.

How are people handling this scenario, or can someone provide us some recommendations on how to make this work with less pain?

Comment: Would love to hear an answer to this as well as I'm dealing with this right now and it is a major pain.

Comment: @mwright does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681762/how-to-handle-xml-html-in-git-feature-branch-workflow) answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

We've handled this by adding a `.gitattributes` file in the root of the project with the following in it:

```
*.pbxproj binary merge=union
```

I'm sure there are [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681762/how-to-handle-xml-html-in-git-feature-branch-workflow) as suggested, but this did the trick in a pinch.