# Git management with iPhone development

Tags: ios, git, storyboard

In working on an iPhone application, what is a good method for working with multiple developers? I have run into several git conflict from simultaneous modifications to the Storyboard file. Is there a good method around this?

Comment: Are you using xcode 6?

Comment: Yes, we are using xcode 6

Comment: If you are still having issues, try splitting up your storyboard into multiple storyboards in a way that makes sense. For example, if you have a menu with 5 different items, can you make a storyboard for each one that contains only the nibs for items inside that menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storyboard files are stored as XML so you're going to run into the same types of issues that XML files have when tracked with git.

[Check out this answer for more technical info on using git attributes and custom merge drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1690981/3841460)

Storyboard XML is not that hard to read from a human perspective (compared to old XIB files) so if the changes are small and not on the same object it can be trivial to use the merge tool in Xcode to resolve conflicts.

To avoid the conflicting situations as much as possible you could set up your project to use multiple storyboard files to split things up and minimize the chances for conflicting changes to a single large storyboard.  Use `+storyboardWithName:bundle:` to load the storyboards when needed.