# application model of leanft gets corrupted while pushing the code in git

Tags: xml, git, automation, leanft

I am working on LeanFT project and use local git for maintain it. Multiple team members are working on same project and do commit and push the code. But while pushing the code application model which is in format of xml get corrupted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681762/how-to-handle-xml-html-in-git-feature-branch-workflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle xml/html in git feature branch workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681762/how-to-handle-xml-html-in-git-feature-branch-workflow)