# How to setup git merge / git pull for xml files?

Tags: git, merge, git-diff

I have the following situation:

Original test.xml file:

```
<li>
  <span>BA</span>
</li>
```

File with committed local changes:

```
<li>
  <span>BA</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span>CE</span>
</li>
```

File with remote changes received through `git pull`:

```
<li>
  <span>BA</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span>DF</span>
</li>
```

`git pull` is identifying only the lines with the new `<span>`s as changes, is there any option to use with git pull / git merge which can avoid this situation?

**UPDATE**:
This is the file with the conflict as it is detected:

```
<li>
  <span>BA</span>
</li>
<li>
<<<<<<< HEAD
  <span>CE</span>
=======
  <span>DF</span>
>>>>>>> master
</li>
```

While I was expecting something like:

```
<li>
  <span>BA</span>
</li>
<li>
<<<<<<< HEAD
<li>
  <span>CE</span>
</li>
=======
<li>
  <span>DF</span>
</li>
>>>>>>> master
</li>
```

I´ve tried the `--strategy-option=patience` argument on `git pull` but it doesn´t any effect at all.

This is only a simple example. Actually this problem is happening with `.resx` files which are edited through the default visual studio editor.

Comment: What would you like to see? Because from what I can gather, the conflict has to be there only for the last 3 lines because the first three lines were not modified on either of the 2 branches so.....

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes! That´s what I expected, but actually git identifies only the <span>CE</span> as a conflict.

Comment: Can you show us (add it to the question) what git is showing you as the conflict?

Comment: @eftshift0 Sure! Added the file with the conflicts.

Comment: Git is realizing that the opening/closing <li></li> lines are the same on both branches so it's saying something like: Ok... this part of the change between both branches is the same so won't complain about it which is what I would think developers would like to get.

Comment: Right @eftshift0, that is the point, but actually I m getting this problem on resx files, and these are edited with a tool I can config to edit the xml in a way I avoid that conflicts. So the point is, how could I setup git to use some kind of pessimistic algorithm that don´t assume those lines (<li>) from different branches/commits as equivalent.

Comment: Changing merge.conflictstyle to diff3 caused as a side effect the git work as expected. But, why?

Comment: Setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` tells Git to write the merge-base text into the work-tree, along with the stage 2 and stage 3 versions, inside the conflict marker region. It has no other effect, and if you write a custom merge driver, it's irrelevant. The right way to do this is with a custom merge driver, but writing a correct custom merge driver for XML is extraordinarily difficult.

Comment: @torek, this is the point, after `merge.conflictStyle`, the conflict region included the `<li>`s as expected. There is absolutely nothing about write custom merge drivers or something like.

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr: Aha, after experimenting, I see what you mean. However, there's no room in comments for the formatting needed to describe it properly. I think I'll add an answer to the linked duplicate.