# Git Merge Driver - File Attributes

Tags: git, merge, path, driver

When using a custom driver for merging in Git what is the full file path of the Git attributes /arguments you pass to the driver?

Ex:

```
driver = filfre %O %A %B
```

What is the full file path of the three files, `%O`, `%A`, and `%B`?

-Tanner

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the example I posted about [How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp).

That scenario involves a merge driver, which you can tweak to display those three variable.

```
keepmine.sh

echo
echo origin $1
echo origin content:
cat $1
echo
echo local  $2
echo local content:
cat $2
echo
echo remote $3
echo remote content:
cat $3
exit 0
```

Here what it returned to me:

```
C:\Prog\Git\tests\CopyMerge>git merge hisBranch

origin .merge_file_a08152
origin content:
  b

local .merge_file_b08152
local content:
  b
  myLineForB

remote .merge_file_c08152
remote content:
  b
  hisLineForB
```

So in this instance, it appears to be generating three **local temp files**, names `merge_file_xxx`.

---

As mentioned by [BlackEye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354768/blackeye) in the comment and in BlackEye's answer "[Git Merge Driver - How to find out full path of merged file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30659295/6309)", [commit ef45bb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef45bb1f8156030446658d5bfb3983ce214a9e16) introduced (git 2.5, July 2015) **the original path to external drivers with `%P`**.

Comment: But there should be a way to retrieve the original file path I think.

What about today, 5 years later? Any suggestion?

Comment: The original file path can now (since 2.5) be passed to the merge driver using the parameter %P.

Comment: @BlackEye Good find! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.