# Best practice for using multiple .gitignore files

Tags: git, github, gitignore

There exists a collection of useful `.gitignore` files at
https://github.com/github/gitignore. Every ignores file there has an extension `.gitignore`, e.g. Java.gitignore, vim.gitignore. When I put these files directly into a workdir, they don't work.

Is it necessary to create a single file `.gitignore` and merge the constituent files into it?

Accordingly, when using a `--global` `.gitignore` file, it seems the config points to a single file. If for instance I want to apply all `.gitignore` files in a Global/ directory, should I manually merge them into a single file? If so, it's extra work to keep this merged file up to date with the "official" collection.

To reiterate, I acknowledge that we can use different `.gitignore` files in different directories, but it is not what I want. I want to apply multiple `.gitignore` files in a single directory.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To clarify: a projects gitignore file is called `.gitignore`

---

Background:

A `.gitignore` refers to the directory that it's in, which is either the top level or descendent of a directory with a .git repository, i.e. a ".git/" directory.

There can be multiple `.gitignore` files in any sub directories but the Best Practice is to have **one** `.gitignore` in a given projects root and have that file reference sub-directories as necessary, e.g. images/yearly/recent  Otherwise it is be tricky to know "which" .gitignore file to look at to find something that's being ignored.  Given that you can use patterns as file names that could be pretty tricky!

I also recommend *avoiding* using a global `.gitignore` file which applies to *all* projects on your machine, although you might keep a template around for using with new projects.  The main consideration here is that your `.gitignore` will be different from other developers (which may or may not exist) and so the result is undetermined.  One example of an exception to this is using a global `.gitignore` file for IDE files that I don't want in any project that I open on my machine so I use a global `.gitigore` with an entry for .idea/ files (rubyMine).

---

The intent of the templates you see listed is that normally you are writing the code for a *given file* in a specific language.  Given this, a template that is based on the language is frequently sufficient.

If there are multiple languages in the code base, then used you will need to combine multiple `.gitignore`'s for those languages, which can be done in a multitude of ways such as:

```
cat .gitignore1 .gitignore2 > .gitignore # if .gitignore doesn't exist yet
cat .gitignore1 >> .gitignore # Add to it if it already exists
paste .gitignore1 .gitignore # Add to it if it already exists
```

---

Hot(ish) off the press (summer 2014):

Gitignorer is a simple utility that aids in the creation of .gitignore files. It pulls specific (specified) .gitignore templates, with common files to exclude, from github.com/github/gitignore, mashes them together, and saves them to a .gitignore in the current directory.

Example usage:

```
gitignorer create c java python
```

Gitignorer is currently available in the AUR over at https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gitignorer/ and on GitHub at https://github.com/zachlatta/gitignorer

---

Comment: So essentially... yes, you will have to manually copy/paste into one file. (unless I'm misunderstanding this answer).

Comment: Agreed but I feel a need to specify some terminology.  We are talking about the difference between a GLOBAL (cross-repository) .gitignore and a project-root .gitignore (applies to all files in ONE repo).  A project-root approach has worked best for me, too, copying entries from one project to another as needed.  A global .gitignore seems to have a lot of potential to cause confusion.

Comment: added a little more info to aid clarity.

Comment: Added more info on avoiding global generally but consider it for IDE files.

Comment: Relates to this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305869/are-multiple-gitignores-frowned-on/3307252#3307252, which is more favorable to using multiple .gitignore files.

Comment: You can use https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore which create 1 big gitignore based on criteria for example: intellij java maven
https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/intellij,java,maven