# IntelliJ - package com.esotericsoftware.kryonet does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kryonet

I'm trying to fix my IntelliJ so that I can successfully build my project again. After rebasing my code from my team's repo, I'm no longer able to find the necessary kryonet files... a bunch of `.idea` files were deleted.

I've tried the following:

- Add the libraries:
  [image: screen1]
- Add the dependencies
  [image: screen2]

However, I'm still getting the errors about the package not being found. What am I doing wrong?

**bonus points**: What .idea files should I exclude from my `.gitignore`?

Comment: `What .idea files should I exclude from my .gitignore?` - Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274424/best-practice-for-using-multiple-gitignore) SO post and [this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore) one on Github.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try this, it has saved my bacon quite a few times:
Begin by importing all the libraries, once it looks good do:
`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

This should refresh the cache and hopefully fix your problem.