# Is it possible to relocate .gitignore file itself?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have two git repositories in one folder. I am able to relocate the `.git` directory and work with both repos using `--git-dir=/path/to/.git` and `--work-tree=/path/to/code`. However, i can't find any options to relocate the `.gitignore` file, which is currently in the root path of the repositories and is considered by both of them. I also thought about using `-c <.gitignoreOptionWhichIDontKnow>="/path/to/.gitignore"` but cannot find any options to relocate my .gitignore file.

**Is it possible to relocate .gitignore file?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The synopsis of [the documentation for gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) mentions several locations:

```
$HOME/.config/git/ignore, $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, .gitignore
```

The first is a global user-dependent ignore file, the second is what you're looking for, and the third is what you are complaining about. If I understand you correctly.

So yes, you can relocate the content of the `.gitignore` file to `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`. It's not total freedom, but it does move the file out of the root of the repository.

Comment: Hmmm.... I've read the documentation and totally ignored the GIT_DIR variant because of *Aristotle Pagaltzis* comment on his own answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3321437/1810087). However, it's what i was searching for, thank you :)