# cargo publish is not ignoring files in .gitignore

Tags: git, rust, rust-cargo

```
» cargo publish
    Updating crates.io index
warning: manifest has no license, license-file, documentation, homepage or repository.
See https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#package-metadata for more info.
error: 1 files in the working directory contain changes that were not yet committed into git:

rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
```

Committing this file or to deleting it every time I push changes would both be terrible options. It is listed in ./.gitignore, but cargo seems not to care. I'm fairly sure cargo is supposed to care, and historically, has, but this would be a strange bug, so I thought I should ask if I'm missing something before reporting.

The project is in a subdirectory (/rust/) inside of a larger git repo.

/rust/.gitignore, and /.gitignore say

```
/rust/rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
/rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
*.sublime-workspace
```

rusttermpose.sublime-workspace is not among git's tracked files

```
» git ls-files
Cargo.toml
README.md
examples/simple.rs
longterm.term
rusttermpose.sublime-project
sexp tests.sexp
shortterm.term
shortwood.sexp
src/lib.rs
src/parsers/mod.rs
src/parsers/termpose_parser.rs
src/parsers/woodslist_parser.rs
src/wooder.rs
tests.term
wood_derive/Cargo.toml
wood_derive/src/lib.rs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's a bug. Been there since /10/18

It only afflicts crates in subdirectories of the git project.

https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6188

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct, you can mention it as:

```
# Workspace files
*.sublime-workspace
```

It will ignore `all` the files with `.sublime-workspace` extension.

You can also do:

```
/rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
```

But not:

```
./rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
```

i.e. do it relative to your root.

You can also do (to ignore files in sub directories):

```
**/*.sublime-workspace
```

or (including the current directory)

```
**.sublime-workspace
```

If you are unsure of the exact directory structure.

Comment: The project now contains two gitignores, one at root, and the other in the rust crate directory, each containing
`
/rust/rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
/rusttermpose.sublime-workspace
*.sublime-workspace
`
It hasn't helped.

Comment: If you have multiple gitignores then managing them become a headache. Please refer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305869/are-multiple-gitignores-frowned-on so you have to provide the paths with respect to the current directory in which your gitignore is.

Comment: @mako I edited my answer. Hope this will work for you.