# Can you have additional .gitignore per directory within a single repo?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, gitignore

Can you create a `.gitignore` file in a directory that only applies to files (and directories) within that directory?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Try it, it works fine.  Put a `.gitignore` in the root of your repo, and put another `.gitignore` with additional things to ignore in a subdirectory.

Comment: Does the .gitignore in the subdirectory replace the root .gitignore? Or does it add to it?

Comment: @dsula the .gitignore in the subdirectory adds to the root .gitignore (does not just replace it).

Answer (score 15):

Similar question was: [Are multiple `.gitignore`s frowned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305869/are-multiple-gitignores-frowned-on) (Jul 2010)

Or if you can have different version of a `.gitignore` file per branch:  [Using github to host public git repositories whilst ensuring that sensitive data files remain untracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250040/using-github-to-host-public-git-repositories-whilst-ensuring-that-sensitive-data/2250144#2250144) (Feb 2010)

Further perhaps related: [How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s/930495#930495)

Answer (score 3):

You can just specify files to ignore in a format such as

```
Xyz/*.abc
```

in the .gitignore in the root directory, potentially removing the need for separate ignore files.