# Can I add a .gitignore file just for me that overrides the project .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am using Git in Android Studio on a OS X machine, and I would like to have a personal `.gitignore` file that overrides the `.gitignore` that are in the project (I want mine to ignore `.iml` files). Can this be done and how?

I have tried to create a `.gitignore` file in my home dir with the following lines in:

```
# Android Studio
.*.iml
*.iml
```

And the I have used this command to make git use my file `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`, but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot override the `.gitignore` file (if any) that sits in your repo's root directory, because it takes precedence over everything else, incl. any "core excludesfile".

Comment: Related: [Can you have multiple .gitignore files within a single repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730486/can-you-have-multiple-gitignore-files-within-a-single-repo)

Comment: No it did not work, I can not get it to ignore the .iml files :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git ignore files only locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Instead of creating a new `.gitignore` file, you [should use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906964/1860929) the `.git/info/exclude` file to setup ignore rules specific to your clone of the repo.

So, basically, go to your project root, and run

```
cd $PROJECT_ROOT
echo "*.iml" >> .git/info/exclude
```

Note that the the pattern `*.iml` will take care of files of kind `.*.iml` as well, so you can make do with one ignore rule.

Also, this complements the existing ignore rules in `.gitignore` and ignore rules of `.gitignore` will still be applied.

---

It seems you are already tracking the `.iml` files in your Git repo, so you can try removing them from Git using

```
git rm -r *.iml
git commit -m "removed *.iml"
```

Note that this will untrack them from the master repository as well once you do a push.

Otherwise, you can use `git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>` to ignore changes to those files locally.
And afterwards, the gitignore rules should work all right.

Comment: Can this be used to override a `.gitignore` rule? (ex: overriding `*.jar` by using `!*.jar` in `.git/info/exclude`)