# Complex git rebase maneuver

Tags: git

Looking at the `git-rebase` man page, I didn't see any diagrams that looked like what I want (except some seem to do the reverse of what I want), and playing around with `--onto` didn't get me what I wanted either.

Let me see if I can draw a diagram like the ones from the `git-rebase` man page (the vertical bars to the left are to make Markdown format it correctly):

```
|      o-o-o-o-branch2
|     /
| -o-o-A-master-o-branch1-o-o-my_WIP_branch
```

`branch1` is probably not actually important here, but I included it anyway.  What I want to do is get this (omitting the `'`s that that usually accompany the `git-rebase` man page diagrams):

```
|     o-o-o-o-branch2-o-branch1-o-o-my_WIP_branch
|    /
|-o-o-A-master
```

Basically, I want to put my `my_WIP_branch` work over the `branch2` work without having to deal with merge conflicts involved in the group of commits labeled `A`.  Is there any way to do this other than manually cherry-picking each commit over `branch2` (or at least is there maybe an easy way to do that?)?  By the way, there will be merge conflicts, so ideally it should be a git command or group of git commands that handle those gracefully (e.g., `git rebase` handles them gracefully, `git am` and `git apply` do not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange... because this should be a classic case of [`rebase --onto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369426/how-to-move-certain-commits-to-another-branch-in-git/2369516#2369516).

You have:

```
     o-o-o-o <--branch2
    /
 o-o-o-A <--master
        \
         -o-o <--branch1
             \
              -o-o <--my_WIP_branch
```

You want:

```
                  -o-o <--my_WIP_branch
                 /
             -o-o <--branch1
            /
     o-o-o-o <--branch2
    /
 o-o-o-A <--master
```

That should be:

```
$ git rebase --onto branch2 master my_WIP_branch
```

it will replay any commit not on master, but from where you can reach my_WIP_branch (meaning the commits from branch2 are not eligible).
See my [other SO answer for merge conflict instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491), and the ["resolving merge conflicts" section](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge) of the Git manual. (you can [accept all merges with *your* version, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822391/accept-all-merge-conflicts-in-git))

Comment: Right, that worked.  `--onto` has 6 possible permutations, so I guess I didn't try the correct one.

Comment: @asmeurer: actually, considering `master` is the common ancestor of `my_WIP_branch` and `branch2`, a simple `git checkout my_WIP_branch` followed by `git rebase branch2` should have been enough.

Comment: no, the problem was that `master` wasn't an ancestor of `branch2` (take another look at my diagram), and I wasn't ready to handle the merge conflicts involved with rebasing `branch2` over master.

Comment: @asmeurer: riiight. I get it now. I have edited my answer to better reflect the `master` state in relation with `branch2`. The `rebase --onto` is truly made for this kind of situation.