# move branch from master commit to previous master commit

Tags: git

Let's asssume I've got commits

`COMMIT_1` `COMMIT_2` in my `master` branch. 
I've made `checkout` from `COMMIT_2` to create new branch `bugFix1` but then I realized that I can't merge `COMMIT_2` changes with main repository yet because they are not approved.

So how to move my branch to previous `COMMIT_1` without affecting my changes in `bugFix1` branch? I don't want to have `COMMIT_2` changes either.

Sorry for my bad illustrator's skills
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:

```
x--x--c1--c2      (master)
            \ 
             y--y (bugfix1)
```

You can do a:

```
git checkout bugfix1
git rebase --onto c1 master bugfix1

x--x--c1--c2    (master)
        \ 
         y'--y' (bugfix1)
```

You can see another example of `rebase --onto` in:

- "[Complex git rebase maneuver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2885516/6309)".
- "[How to move certain commits to another branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369516/6309)"