# Re: git merge when two different versions of file

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a different version of a file in a development branch than I do in the master. The problem is I want to track those files, so how do I merge development into master without overwriting that file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a merge driver in a `.gitattributes` file, with a "keep mine" directive.

That way, any merge will keep the file currently on the destination branch.

See "[Accept all merge conflicts in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822773/6309)" as an example of such a driver.
See also "[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930495/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the whole development branch into master by doing:

```
git checkout master
git branch development
```

Instead, if you just want to get the changes applied to that file, you can go into the *master* branch and *pick* single commits on the *development* branch through the **git cherry-pick** command.