# Avoiding merge conflict

Tags: git, git-merge

Let's say I have a file in the master branch:

```
Hello World!
```

I create a new branch A and modify that same file to:

```
Hello World!
and a little more
```

Then I modify that same file in the master branch

```
Hello World, the bug is fixed!
```

Is there a way to merge the 2 branches into:

```
Hello World, the bug is fixed!
and a little more
```

without having to resolve a conflict?

ps: completely new to git so I might miss something obvious - I'm using netbeans as an IDE and using the built-in merge function

Comment: possible duplicate of [strategy for git and append-mostly files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841127/strategy-for-git-and-append-mostly-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conflicts arise out of ambiguities and are sometimes unavoidable. Try using a tool like [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) to help quickly resolve your merge-conflicts and make it a less painful experience.

I would also recommend that you first perform a rebase from your working branch to pull in the changes from master before attempting the merge. It is good practice to settle conflicts locally in your branch first so that you have trivial fast-forward merges.

Answer (score 3):

A conflict arises when two changes are modifying the same part of code. It cannot be automatically resolved with machine intelligence without human involvement, because the machine cannot know exactly whether a literal merge would be valid or not. Consider the following example:

The base version:

```
char s[200];
```

1st modified version:

```
char s[100]; // reduce array size
```

2nd modified version:

```
char s[200];
s[199] = 0;
```

If the merge tool does what you suggested, the result would be:

```
char s[100]; // reduce array size
s[199] = 0;
```

Obviously, the result is wrong.

So don't expect the machine can resolve the conflict for you. We programmers are guaranteed to have this privilege in the foreseeable future, :)