# Avoid merge conflicts in stylesheets

Tags: css, git, github, stylesheet, merge-conflict-resolution

Most of the time, merge conflicts are not a major issue. However, for my team, it's become a problem in our main stylesheet where we all append new classes to the bottom of the file. This leads to merge conflicts in github.

What are best practices when organizing .css files to avoid merge conflicts?

Comment: what's worse is when git DOESN'T think there's a conflict and deletes chunks of css/sass on when merging a branch because it gets the block boundaries wrong (usually because someone forgot a newline between two css declarations, but I've seen it just decide to delete whole chunks even when the newlines were there)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to avoid these types of merge conflicts. You have two options that I see:

1. Use a **custom merge driver**. See [strategy for git and append-mostly files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841127/strategy-for-git-and-append-mostly-files). This is fairly complex and I haven't done this myself. Personally I see too much potential for work magically disappearing.
2. **Split your css** into multiple files. You could then use something like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with [cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin#combine-two-files-into-one-output-file) to compile them into a single file. This wouldn't eliminate the issue entirely, but it reduce conflicts enough to be manageable.