# Making a merge driver for a repo to merge PR

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I own a repo **A** that contains a file **F**, within the repo A I have two branches **PRD and TST**.

In each of these branches I want to keep a seprate version of F

Everytime I need to make a change to my repo, I create a branch from my fork version of PRD, work on it, and then first make a PR to TST (call it **PR1**) branch in central repo to validate my changes and then once it's validated, I then make a PR to PRD (Call it PR2) branch in central repo.

The issue here is that since I have separate version of F, every change in PRD branch of F will cause a conflict in PR1, and I don't want that file to change in TST branch.

I've read about making a merge driver and choose ours strategy, but then how to make it working within central repo so that PR will fix conflict automatically ?
Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839496/add-a-git-merge-driver-to-the-repository) , but the answer is not answering the question ...

Is this possible without making the file a git submodule ?

Comment: Every change may not necessarily cause a conflict.  You could probably improve your workflow, but regardless at the end of a sprint when you merge and reconcile everything you may get conflicts, this is a fact of life.

Comment: I couldn't explain the whole flow, but in reality the conflict will happen very often.