# Can I implement my own Python-based git merge strategy?

Tags: python, git, merge

I developed a Python library for merging large numbers of XML files in a very specific way. These XML files are split up and altered by multiple users in my group and it would be much easier to put everything into a Git repo and have git-**merge** manage everything via my Python code.

It seems that implementing my code for git-**mergetool** is possible, but I would have to write my own code to manage the conflict returns for the internal git-merge (i.e. parse the >>>>>>> <<<<<<< ======= identifiers), which would be more time consuming.

So, is there a way to have Git's merge command automatically use my Python code instead of its internal git-merge?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry about that -- updated with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom merge driver that's used for certain filetypes instead of Git's default merge driver.

- [Relevant documentation in gitattributes(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver)

Some related StackOverflow questions:

- [Git - how to force merge conflict and manual merge on selected file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074452/git-how-to-force-merge-conflict-and-manual-merge-on-selected-file)
- [How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s)

Comment: The OP might also find this external link useful: http://vlists.pepperfish.net/pipermail/baserock-dev-baserock.org/2012-September/000658.html