# Git merge updates to a past branch

Tags: git, merge

I have this project I'm working on where I'm building a framework for some content. During development I had a bunch of demo content so I can see what I'm doing essentially. This was all being done in the `dev` branch.

At some point I branched off the `dev` branch and created a new branch called `demo`. Since the branch the `dev` branch has had all demo content removed. Files were deleted and existing files were also modified to leave a vanilla branch for development to continue.

Now I'm at the stage where I want to work on demo content again. However because the `demo` branch is outdated, I intend on merging the updates from `dev -> demo`.

The problem at hand is that if I were to carry on with the merge, the deleted files will automatically be carried across as it won't see a conflict and some of the files that were also updated to remove the demo content will carry across.

In a nutshell, I want to merge the `dev` into `demo` and not end up deleting anything as part of it.

```
            v dev - origin/HEAD
o - o - o - o - ...
     \       \
      o - - - o <- proposed update
      ^ demo
```

That's essentially what I want to do, extremely basic, but I can't think of a way to do it without destroying anything in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom Git merge driver, q.v. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074452/git-how-to-force-merge-conflict-and-manual-merge-on-selected-file).  The meat and potatoes of this method is creating a script which does the same thing which Git usually does during a merge, but then always returns `1` at the end of the script, triggering a manual conflict resolution:

```
#!/bin/bash
git merge-file "${1}" "${2}" "${3}"
exit 1
```

There are a few other configuration steps, but the jist is to force Git to a manual resolution.

An alternative to this approach would be to simply do the normal merge and then restore the files afterwards.  You could checkout the deleted files via:

```
git checkout <SHA-1> path/to/deleted/file
```

where `<SHA-1>` is the commit hash from the previous commit in your `demo` branch, and `path/to/deleted/file` is the path to the deleted file.  After you have finished, you can make a new commit for the restored files.

Comment: Not as elegant as I expected, but maybe I just had high expectations for git. Thanks! It's exactly what I wanted to do :)

Comment: @SteppingHat I second that, it is not very elegant, but at least it is possible.