# How to retrieve deleted code but still keeping the new code?

Tags: git

So, I have this case of merge commit:

```
           --D--E--
          /        \
--A--B--C-          ---H---
          \        /
           --F--G--
```

Where :

- Commit A, B, and C is in `develop` branch
- Commit D, E is in `feature` branch
- Commit F, G is in `develop` branch, merged from another feature branch
- Commit H is merge `feature` into `develop`

The problem is, when i merged `feature` into `develop`, we lost some code introduced before the branch, for example :

Before the branch (A, B, C and before that), in file Z we have :

```
Code 1
Code 2
```

In `feature` branch (D, E), the committer removed `Code 2` , he also added `Code 3` so the file becomes :

```
Code 1
Code 3
```

In develop branch (F, G), `Code 4` is added so the file becomes :

```
Code 1
Code 2
Code 4
```

Now after the merge (H), the file becomes :

```
Code 1
Code 3
Code 4
```

But the merge deleted `Code 2` because it was deleted in `feature`.

What I want :

```
Code 1
Code 2
Code 3
Code 4
```

The merge didn't show any conflict for this file.

So how do I keep the old code while still having the new code?

One thing to note is that I have pushed this merge to the remote repo.

Comment: Your diagram is a little bit off, because merging _two_ branches into the `develop` branch should result in _two_ merge commits, not one.

Comment: You are in a bit of a conundrum.  There is a way to tell Git to keep only the versions of one party in a merge.  But in your case, this won't work because you want changes from both branches.  One option here would be to use the history from your IDE Git plugin to simply add back the missing code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, the merge is from `feature` to `develop`, the other branch is already merged which results in commit F and G, so there's only one merge here. The merge from another branch which becomes F and G is not included because it's irrelevant.

Comment: "One option here would be to use the history from your IDE Git plugin to simply add back the missing code."

@TimBiegeleisen So basically doing the good ol' copy and paste?

Comment: The bottom line: This sort of thing can happen in Git.  Perhaps the best you could do here would be to force a merge conflict on every file modified by both branches.  And you can read about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074452/git-how-to-force-merge-conflict-and-manual-merge-on-selected-file

Comment: You need to realize that Git saw a newer feature branch removing some code, so it took that as being the version of things you actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Before I get into all the details below, if you're just asking how to *find the deleted code (relatively) easily*, you can run `git diff` on the merge base and the two commits.  This is the same set of diffs that `git merge` merged.  To find the merge base, use `git merge-base`:

```
$ merge=1234567...   # or some other way to locate the merge commit
$ git merge-base --all ${merge}^1 ${merge}^2
```

Ideally, this prints out just one commit ID, which is the merge base.  You can then `git diff` that hash ID against `${merge}^1` (the merge's first-parent) and `${merge}^2` (the merge's second parent).

---

As [Tim Biegeleisen noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413806/how-to-retrieve-deleted-code-but-still-keeping-the-new-code#comment68077491_40413806), your diagram does not quite seem to match your text.  Fortunately, from the text we can describe a much simpler situation, where problems arise from separate files' interactions.  The *effect* is the same, but the setup is easier:

```
       A   <-- branch1
      /
...--*
      \
       B   <-- branch2
```

Here we have one commit `A` on `branch1` and a different commit `B` on `branch2`, both descending from a common base branch whose tip commit is `*`.  (We only really need to care that commit `*` exists, for the upcoming merge.)

Suppose that in the merge base, there is a function `prepare()` defined in `shared.py` that is not actually used anywhere.  It was *meant* for use in `branch1`, and is now used in `branch1` from `work.py`.  But the author of commit `B` in `branch2` decided to *delete* `prepare()` precisely because it was never used.

You now wish to combine commits `A` and `B`, perhaps as a new commit on `branch1`:

```
$ git checkout branch1
$ git merge branch2
```

Git compares commit `*` to commit `A`: this says, among other things, "add call to `prepare` in file `work.py`".  This is no problem for Git, because commit `B` does not even *touch* file `work.py`.

Git then compares commit `*` to commit `B`: this says, among other things, "remove call to `prepare` from file `shared.py`".  This is no problem for Git either, because commit `A` does not touch this part of `shared.py` (and maybe even does not touch `shared.py` at all).

The result is a new merge commit:

```
       A---C   <-- branch1
      /   /
...--*   /
      \ /
       B   <-- branch2
```

## Git is a tool (pun maybe not intended), not a solution

It is *your* job, as the person doing the merge, to tell whether Git got the merge right.  Git will get this merge *wrong*, in part because whoever wrote commit `B` did the wrong thing.  If you simply run `git merge` and push the result because the merge succeeded, that's your mistake right there, and you will need to recover from it.  We'll get to this in a moment, but first, let's look at ways to avoid or correct the mistake early.

#### Test thoroughly

This is not perfect but has the advantage of being easy to do by computer.  If there are good tests, you can do the `git merge` and then run the tests.  If the tests fail, you know something is wrong with the merge—so stop using it, and go back and fix it.

#### Scan the merge manually

This catches more errors, but also misses more errors, because it can catch problems that are not being tested-for, but relies on fallible humans.

If you spot a problem this way that does not show up during testing, you may be able to write an automated test to detect it.  If that does not take too long, that's a good idea.

## Options for fixing the problem before pushing

Since the merge is not used anywhere, you can just un-make it:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

which discards the merge (commit `C`) so that `branch1` points to `A` again.  We do not need to keep the index or work-tree either, since Git made the merge in a fully automated manner.  We now must decide how to fix the problem.

#### Option 1: restore the missing code on `branch2`

```
$ git checkout branch2
... edit shared.py to restore the code ...
$ git add shared.py; git commit
```

This gives us:

```
       A      <-- branch1
      /
...--*
      \
       B--C   <-- branch2
```

where a merge to create `D` on `branch1` will again succeed, but not remove the necessary code.  We can re-merge and re-test.

#### Option 2: do the merge but *don't commit it*:

```
$ git merge --no-commit branch2
```

Now we can fix up `shared.py`, `git add` it, and commit.  This option is fast, but a little bit dirty, because we now have a merge commit that has a manual fixup from a problem *not* seen by Git itself.  If the problem is found through automated testing, and we consistently use automated testing, and for some reason we have to repeat this merge in the future, we'll re-discover the problem.  If we also comment on this in the merge message, that's probably sufficient.

This option *does* have the advantage that we did not have to add another commit to `branch2`.

There's a slight variant of Option 1 that is more work than either, but may be the best of all for *some* cases (those where disturbing `branch2` is a problem): make a *new* branch with the fixed version of `B`, and merge that, so that we get:

```
       A---D   <-- branch1
      /   /
...--*   C     <-- fixed-branch2
      \ /
       B       <-- branch2
```

## Option 3: Fixing things after-the-fact

Of course, what we have now is that the merge has been pushed (or published).  Retracting published merges is even harder than retracting published regular (non-merge) commits, because reverting a merge sets us up to have a different but related failure on subsequent merges.  So we can just leave the "bad" version out there and simply make a fix and push that:

```
       A---C--D   <-- branch1
      /   /
...--*   /
      \ /
       B   <-- branch2
```

Commit `D`, which we make as the new tip of `branch1`, just puts back the missing function—the same as we would do if we were fixing `branch2` directly.

This leaves `C` behind as a "broken commit".  That's basically just the way things are: people have that commit it; people are using it; so we're kind of stuck with it.  It causes headaches later if/when we go to use `git bisect` to find a problem, since commit `C` doesn't really work, but the only alternative is to can get *everyone else* to scrub the broken commit `C` from *their* repositories—in which case, you can "rewrite history" to pretend you used one of the first two options in the first place.

(Fortunately `git bisect` *can* deal with broken commits—and if you are going to preserve history, you can use `git notes` to annotate these commits for automation during bisections.  See http://xkcd.com/974/ for details. :-) )