# git pull request with SourceTree squash my changes on same file

Tags: git, git-pull, sourcetree, squash

We use SourceTree. When other person changes some things on same file and commit and push his changes then when i fetch and pull these, my changes on same file squashed and file updated with just his changes there is no my changes. How to solve this problem? Any suggestion?

Thanks all.

Comment: `there is no my changes` ... what do you want to do with your changes?  Are you looking to squash some commits?

Comment: Have you committed your changes before doing fetch & pull ?

Comment: @sajibkhan yes i have commited my changes. But when i pull other person changes on same file, mine changes hidden and file updated with just other person changes

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i expect source tree shows conflict. Because i have committed changes on same file. We are 2 person when we make changes on same file and one person push his changes and other person pull changes my own changes hidden and file updated just other person changes.

Comment: This can happen with Git, which sometimes assumes that your work shouldn't appear at the end of an automatic merge.  There is a way to force a merge conflict on every merge (q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074452/git-how-to-force-merge-conflict-and-manual-merge-on-selected-file)), but this can also be a hassle when you don't want/need it to happen.

Comment: For a quick fix, just bring your changes back and commit.