# Git - how to always take a my branch's content when hitting a conflict?

Tags: git, github

I saw the post "[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp)", which says if you have conflict on a folder, we need to add `.gitattributes` to that folder and then add a merge driver to config file to say always keep my branch's content for this folder.
And this works perfectly fine.

But what if I end with up conflicts on several folders/files and want to keep my version for these. It doesn't make sense to create `.gitattributes` file in every folder that has conflicts.

So is there a way to do this - like if am merging `Branch-A` to `Branch-B` and end up with so many conflicts, I need a way by which I can keep `Branch-B` contents for all the conflicts.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take branch B's version for *all* conflicts, you can simply use a merge strategy option:

```
git merge -X ours branchB
```

This will merge normally (using the default recursive strategy) until it runs into a conflicting hunk, at which point it'll automatically take branch B's version of the hunk.

Comment: I got another suggestion from a guy, asking me to do git checkout --ours/theirs filename to merge the files.... do you see any potential difference between the two?