# How to forbid Git merge certain branches

Tags: git, merge

I need support of 3 versions of my program. Where most files are

joint (common) but several files contain different content for each version.

I'll probably use 4 branches A,B,C,D in Git.

Form example project Ice-cream:

```
____________________________________________________
Cup.txt: { Waffle cup } – common file for all version

Filling.txt { banana } - special file for B version
Filling.txt { strawberries } - special file for C version
Filling.txt { vanilla } - special file for D version
____________________________________________________
```

A - branch suitable only for global files (Cup.txt)

B,C,D - branch suitable only for Filling.txt file.

For this strategy I need allow to merge only in one direction: A => B,C,D

My question is how to forbid merging from B,C,D to A branches in Git?

[image: how to forbid merging reverse direction]

Comment: @Robin, if you're going to insist on such a tag, please at least contribute a wiki excerpt to explain why it's not a horrible abomination of a meta tag.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding source code, it is best to avoid complex merge strategy, and modify PrintBill in order to:

- separate content specific to client A and B
- build the right executable for client A and client B by choosing the right source

The idea is the same than the one initially written below: avoid any complex merge strategy.

Now if that kind of refactoring isn't possible, you can try and [declare a **merge driver**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10012919/6309), but that won't be always called (only in case of conflicts)

---

Another approach would be to avoid versioning `Filling.txt` (that way, no more merge strategy headache).

You can:

- version 3 different files with values for each environment
- setup a `smudge` script (a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) declare [in a `.gitattributes` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) which will automatically on checkout generate, depending on the checked out branch, the right `Filling.txt`

[image: smudge]

Comment: Your suggestion good work if “Filling.txt” be kind of configuration file. And smudge script copy  from (FillingB.txt, FillingC.txt) to Filling.txt.

But in my project the file “Filling.txt” is a source file, which often edited and must save history on each branch.

Comment: @Jarikus simply make sure your file include templates like @val1@, @val2@, ..., that the smudge script can easily replace. And add a clean script which will update that same file automatically on commit, with any modification you have done to that source file. Like the smudge script,you declare the clean script in a .gitattributes file.

Comment: Templates not convenient to my instance, because  file ‘Filling.txt’ too different on each version.

I`am make scheme, for more approach to my problem:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/pDb0D.png

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think this is really what you want to do.

You want to forbid merging in **B-specific stuff into A.**

But merging general bug fixes from B to A should be fine.

So you should keep B-specific stuff in separate files.

Anyway, what you need is something like a git pre-receive hook on the "central server", which checks for and prevents additions of "banned files", I think.

But note that if you *do* keep B-specific stuff in separate files, you don't even need to use git branches to solve this problem. You can just use separate projects with dependencies between them.