# .gitattributes merge strategy

Tags: git

I tried to add a merge strategy to my .gitattributes file in my repository.
But when I merge another branch with that (different) file it results in a merge-conflict - auto merge failed.

Here's what I try to do.

.gitattributes:

```
backend/library/project/config.php merge=ours
```

Branches:

- production
- staging

in production I have config.php'A and in staging I have config.php'B.

```
> git checkout production

> git merge staging 

> Auto-merging backend/library/project/config.php
> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in backend/library/project/config.php
> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I tried adding the line to .git/info/attributes as well as adding quotes to ..merge="ours".

Has anybody an idea what I am doing wrong? (Git-version is 1.7.4.4)
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two excellent Stack Overflow responses which address this problem:

[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s)

and

[.gitattributes & individual merge strategy for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465122/gitattributes-individual-merge-strategy-for-a-file)

I'd suggest reading through the top answer in the first link. It's long, but very detailed and informative.

Comment: Instead of linking to SO questions, please flag the question as a duplicate.