# .gitattributes merge driver is not used

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, gitattributes

At first, I know this question [How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s) but this post doesn't help me and I can't add any comments because of my reputation.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes suggests to set the merge strategy to ours for the path instead of setting a custom merge driver.

What is the benefit and differene of adding a custom merge driver return an exit code 0?

I have a .gitattributes file on my repos top level:

```
pom.xml merge=ours
```

But when I merge two branches with changed pom.xml files the merge can't be resolved:

```
$ git merge origin/master
Auto-merging pom.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in pom.xml
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

And I get a standard merge conflict result:

```
<pom>
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <version>0.88-SNAPSHOT</version>
=======
    <version>0.87.0</version>
>>>>>>> origin/master
</pom>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a merge driver, but that means you have to define it on the git config, as in "[`.gitattributes` & individual merge strategy for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000959/6309)":

```
[merge "ours"]
    name = "Keep ours merge"
    driver = true
```

That allows for a merge strategy for a file, or set of files, as opposed to the `-s` option for [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) **[strategies](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies)**, which doesn't require you to define a driver, but which would resolve the conflict for *all* files (not just for `pom.xml`)

```
git merge -s ours
```

Comment: The problem is we are using Atlassian Stash as our enterprise git repository so we can't specify any parameters for the merge.

The next problem is, I don't know any option to provide the pull request with the merge driver :/ I'm awaiting a reply from Atlassian for this topic.

Comment: @BlackEye but if you define a merge driver, Stash would pick it up, as it reads the `.gitattributes` of your repo.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think Stash uses a temporary repository to merge the pull request. How should such a repository know the merge driver?

Comment: @BlackEye (assuming it does the merge on your workstation) it will see your .gitattributes, since it is a file from your repo. But it will know of the dirver only if it is defined in the global option (`git config --global ...`), because the temporary repo wouldn't see the local config of your local repo.

Comment: Stash is a web application, a frontend to git remotes according to this it manages bare repositories. 

Entries from a bare repository's .git/config are not inherited to cloned repositories, so I don't see any option to provide a config for the temporary repository :/

Comment: @BlackEye it would be easy enough to convince your Stash admin to declare in a global config on the Stash server your merge driver, though.