# Custom Git merge driver with no rename detection

Tags: git, merge

I would like to set up a Git repository with a custom merge driver, and then disable rename detection when merging.

The problem is that, if I use the default recursive strategy, I cannot disable rename detection, and if I use the resolve strategy (not ideal, but good enough), the merge driver is ignored.

Note that I would like to avoid rename detection even when the file contents perfectly match.

.git/config:

```
[merge "my"]
    name = my merge
    driver = my_merge_driver %A %O %B
[merge]
    default = my
```

Attempts:

```
$ git merge -X rename-threshold=200%  # Equivalent to 100%
$ git merge -s resolve                # Custom driver ignored
$ git --version                       # git version 2.2.0-rc0
```

Comment: Is it still ignore with git 2.7.0?

Comment: I guess it is still ignored, reading my old answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22579625/6309

Comment: Indeed, @VonC, I can confirm the exact same behaviour with git version 2.7.0.

Comment: Can you provide any details of what your custom merge driver `my_merge_driver` does, or what problems it solves?

Comment: @javabrett The file contents represent version numbers. The driver basically favours latest versions. The repository represents de facto histories in a system where files (or any logical units) are independently versioned.

Comment: Have you looked into pulling your merge-driver logic up into a custom merge-strategy instead?  You could possibly chain this strategy to call the existing resolve strategy script after your version-number logic has done what it needs to do.

Comment: @javabrett That is certainly an option, but, if possible, I would prefer to reuse the logic in the recursive strategy (except for rename detection, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Git 2.8.0.rc0, the merge-recursive algorithm now accepts an option "no-renames" (commit 4ce064d), so my problem is now solved by

```
$ git merge -X no-renames
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the use case you're planning for this, A good workaround would be to write the filename, along with the version number, in each file.

Comment: I find it a bit ugly, and it will require some (simple) changes on code handling the repository, but, well, it works. Expiring bounty granted. I will wait some more time to see if other answers appear before accepting one.