# Is it possible to patch a submodule in Git from the parent project?

Tags: git, build, diff, git-submodules, patch

I have a project `main` that contains a submodule `foo`. For this particular project, I would like to make a small change to `foo` that only applies to this particular project `main`.

```
main/
  + .git
  + main.c
  + lib/
  |   + bar.c
  + foo/           # My `foo` submodule
      + .git
      + config.h   # The file I want to patch from `main`
      + ...
```

A common solution would be to go down to my submodule, make a commit `Applied patch for main` on a new branch called `main-project`, then push it. Unfortunately, this is a very bad approach because I am making changes to `foo` that only matters to `main`. Also, when I update `foo` to the latest version, I will have to cherry-pick the patch too which introduces a lot of noise in `foo`'s history.

Another solution is to have a real *patch* file on `main` that is applied to `foo` just before the build. Unfortunately as this modifies the submodule content, and I will have uncommitted changed on `foo`, so it is not a good solution either.

The ideal solution would be to track my patch using Git, but at the top-level (e.g. directly on `main`, not on `foo`). Theoretically, it would be possible to add a `blob` on the Git `tree` that points into the submodule location:

```
blob   <sha> main.c
tree   <sha> lib/
commit <sha> foo
blob   <sha> foo/config.h
```

With this idea,  the patched file `config.h` belonging to `foo` will be tracked on `main`.

How is it possible to do it so?

Comment: I don't know many people who regard the records vcs's keep of what's been done as noise, most people I know regard those as a selling point.  If you're going to update your changes for a new vendor release, apply your patches on a new base, I'd think you'd want a vcs to record what's that's been done, so others (perhaps just you six weeks from now) can reproduce and test the work.

Comment: @jthill When the upstream repository is huge and changes often and your patches
are small and rare, it makes a lot of sense, maintenance-wise.  Please post
your concerns in a new question;  I'd like to answer in more details.

Comment: P.S.: I find patch versioning an interesting concept, especially since I only
understood recently why (I think that) it is done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would still go with the second option (have a real patch file on main), but adapt my build process to:

- make a copy of the `config.h` in the submodule
- apply the patch
- build
- restore `config.h` to its original content.

That way, I keep the submodule status unchanged.

The OP adds in the comments:

> But your solution is not working in a IDE, Intellisense will be confused –

True: for that, I would apply automatically the patch on checkout, and remove it on checking, through a [smudge/clean content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40317246/6309).
That way, the patch remains in place during the all session, but would disappear on any git status/diff/checkin.

This is not ideal though, and there does not seem to be a native Git way to handle this.

Comment: As you said it is not ideal. I am wondering how possible it would be to propose this feature on Git

Comment: @nowox I don't see it as a native feature of Git, but this workaround should be enough: if scripted, the script will be part of your sources, making the process clearer.

Comment: Yeah, but your solution is not working in a IDE, Intellisense will be confused

Comment: @nowox Agreed. For that you would need to apply that patch on checkout, and remove it on checkin: that is the content filter driver approach that I describe for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40317246/6309

Comment: Wait, Intellisense isn't smart enough to apply patches during a build?  And this is somehow Git's fault?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way to carry project-specific patches on a vendor history is to clone the vendor repo, carry the changes as a project branch and advertise that clone as the  `.gitmodules` upstream.

This makes work on your changes to the vendor upstream project perfectly ordinary, `git clone --recurse-submodules yourproject` works fine, your-submodule changes can be pushed back to the your-project-submodule upstream (the submodule repo's `origin` remote), everything works.

The only additional fillip is, to update your project's version of the submodule to the latest vendor code somebody has to fetch and merge from the (further-upstream) vendor repo

... but that's also perfectly ordinary: the way to fetch and merge from the vendor repo is, do it. `git remote add vendor u://r/l; git fetch vendor; git merge vendor/master`.  Or if you prefer rebase to merge, do that. Once you've done that, push the results to your submodule's `origin`, your project's version, all as usual.

Answer (score 8):

> The ideal solution would be to track my patch using Git, but at the top-level
>   (e.g. directly on main, not on foo). Theoretically, it would be possible to
>   add a blob on the Git tree that points into the submodule location:

Even if this is doable, personally I find it very convoluted.  Unless this was
implemented natively and included user-facing commands that make it easy to
understand and manage, I'd stay away from it.

#### Alternative 1: Patch

> Is there are more elegant/streamlined way of doing a patch in a git
>   submodule, other than the accepted answer?

If you would like to avoid messing with the submodule at all, I would suggest
copying over/checking out the worktree somewhere else and using only that
during the build.  That way, the submodule is always "clean" (and perhaps
"immutable", from `main`'s point of view) and you only have to worry about it
in the build directory.

Simplified build process example:

```sh
cd main
mkdir -p build
cp -R foo/ build/
cp myconfig.patch build/
cd build
patch <myconfig.patch
make
```

Note that this builds only `foo`, and that `main`'s build process does not need
to be altered besides having to point to `build/` instead of `foo/`.

If you do not intend on modifying `foo` itself/would rather keep it "pristine",
you could also turn it into a bare repository and use
`GIT_WORK_TREE="$PWD/build" git checkout HEAD` instead of `cp`, so that it is
only checked out during the build.  This is similar to how
[makepkg(8)](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/makepkg.8.html) does it (at least in my experience with the AUR) in order
to avoid modifying the original sources (`$source` array vs `$srcdir`).  It
also splits source retrieval from the build itself (`prepare()` vs `build()`).
See also [PKGBUILD(5)](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/PKGBUILD.5.html) and [Creating packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages#PKGBUILD_functions).
In your case, development and an IDE are also involved, so it might be trickier
if you want to inspect both the original and the build files at once.

**Pros**:

- Sources are separated from the build files
- `main` does not affect `foo`
- Does not depend on git/makes it merely a build automation issue
- Only requires a patch file

**Cons**:

- Need to keep the patch file updated (vs rebasing changes)
- Need to change the build process

I'd go with this one if your patches are small and/or very specific to `main`.

**P.S.:** It is possible to go one step further and track `foo`'s version
directly in the build process instead of using submodules if you wanted to:

Move `foo` one directory up, then in the build process:

```sh
cd build
GIT_DIR='../../foo/.git' git checkout "$myrev"
patch <myconfig.patch
make
```

#### Alternative 2: Separate Branch

> Also, when I update foo to the latest version, I will have to cherry-pick the
>   patch too which introduces a lot of noise in foo's history.

You don't really have to cherry-pick it, you could just keep the changes in
your branch instead and **merge** `master` every once in a while.

Personally, I would avoid this unless your changes are much more significant
than the noise caused by keeping it in sync (i.e.: the merges and conflicts).
I find merge commits to be very opaque, especially when conflicts are involved,
as unrelated/accidental changes are harder to detect.

**Rebasing** your commits onto `master` is also an option.

**Pros**:

- No need for a separate repository
- Keeps the worktree in the same place (no need to mess with your IDE)

**Cons**:

- Pollutes `foo`'s repository with unrelated commits (when merging)
- Pollutes `foo`'s repository with unrelated commit objects (when rebasing)
- Murky history of the evolution of your changes to `config.h` (when rebasing)

#### Alternative 3: Soft Fork

> Also, when I update foo to the latest version, I will have to cherry-pick the
>   patch too which introduces a lot of noise in foo's history.
>
> Unfortunately, this is a very bad approach because I am making changes to foo
>   that only matters to main

If you want to change `foo` to suit `main`, but not mess with `foo` upstream,
why not create a soft-fork of `foo`?  If you do not care too much about
`foo-fork`'s history, you could just commit your changes on the `main-project`
branch and keep it in sync with `foo`'s `master` through rebase:

Creating the fork:

```sh
cd foo
git remote add foo-fork 'https://foo-fork.com'
git branch main-project master
git push -u foo-fork main-project
```

Keeping it in sync:

```sh
git checkout main-project
git pull --rebase foo/master
# (resolve the conflicts, if any)
git push foo-fork
```

**Pros**:

- Easy to sync with upstream (e.g.: with `pull --rebase`)
- Keeps the worktree in the same place (no need to mess with your IDE)

**Cons**:

- Murky history of the evolution of your changes to `config.h` (because of
  rebasing)

The added benefit of using a patch instead of rebasing is that you keep the
history of the patch.  But if you want to keep things really simple sync-wise,
I suppose that this is the way.

#### Alternative 4: Hard Fork

If you find that `foo` changes too much/too often and/or you need to patch too
many things, your best bet is probably creating a full fork and cherry-picking
their changes instead.

Answer (score 3):

You might find it makes more sense to use a git subtree rather than a submodule. Subtree copies the other project into a location in the local repository, rather than managing it as a separate repo inside the current repo.

You can apply your change locally as part of your main master branch, then periodically update, merging in changes from upstream.