# Git patch submodule

Tags: git

I have a project with some dependencies which are pulled as git submodules. I have for one of them a small patch to apply (about 6 line changes, nothing significant).

Is there a way to automatically apply this patch when pulling the submodule?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to patch a submodule in Git from the parent project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47562385/is-it-possible-to-patch-a-submodule-in-git-from-the-parent-project)

Answer (score 2):

The `git apply` documentation states [that](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#_submodules):

> If the patch contains any changes to submodules then git apply treats these changes as follows.
>
> If `--index` is specified (explicitly or implicitly), then the submodule
>   commits must match the index exactly for the patch to apply. If any of
>   the submodules are checked-out, then these check-outs are completely
>   ignored, i.e., they are not required to be up to date or clean and
>   they are not updated.
>
> If `--index` is not specified, then the submodule commits in the patch
>   are ignored and only the absence or presence of the corresponding
>   subdirectory is checked and (if possible) updated.

Hence, if you use `git apply` with the `--index` tag, I think you will be able to apply patches to submodules. Make sure to run a `git submodule summary` to check if there are any differences between what the superproject expects and what the submodule actually is. If there are any, do a `git submodule update` and you're all set!

Best.