# GIT merge -keep specific parts of one branch and everything else of the other

Tags: git, git-merge

Here's the scenario

Master branch

-File name: xxx-master.txt

-File content:

`code
code
ID=01
code
code
code`

Dev branch

-File name: xxx-dev.txt

-File content:

`code
code
ID=02
code
code
code`

When merging master into dev, I'd like to keep xxx-dev.txt as the file name and ID=02, but everything else from master.  And vice versa when merging dev into master.  Is that something I can make GIT understand?

Comment: I think you would have to write your own merge-script to do that kind of thing. But may I ask why you want to do that? There is probably a better solution for your problem.

Comment: @FabianH. hard to explain, I simplified the scenario for the purpose of the question.  But basically each branch is its own 'project' in our deployment portal and it needs its own ID and File Name which are stored in a specific file that also contain other information which need to be merged conventionally.

Comment: then this logic should probably not be in your code, but part of you deployment portal. Your portal should set the right environment variables and your code should compile accordingly.

Comment: @FabianH. that doesn't really make sense for my situation, but I probably explained it wrong

Comment: Is this a one-off operation or is this something you expect to do many times in the future?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice many times

Comment: @Traceur It seems to me like there is a better solution to solve this task. If some value differs between development and production, it should not be hardcoded. Instead, you should use environment variables or configuration files so that the value can be set more dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically a case where you need to keep (for a given file, here `xxx-dev.txt`) *different content based on branches*, one way is to:

- version only a template file `xxx-dev.tpl`
- version value files named after the branches: `xxx-dev.dev`, `xxx-dev.master`: since they are different, there is no merge issue.

For that, you would register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) in your submodule repo a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script, associate to the template file (`*-dev.txt`), would generate (automatically on `git checkout`) the actual `xxx-dev.txt` file by looking values in the right `xxx-dev.<branch>` value file.
The generated actual `xxx-dev.txt` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".

Your `smudge` script can determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's promising.  I'll look into it when I have some time, congrats on the +50 rep! :P