# Gitlab and forks. Only update downstream

Tags: git, gitlab, git-fork

Is it possible in Gitlab to have downstream repos whose changes would never go to the upstream, but when modifying the upstream repo all the changes are reflected on the downstream ones?

I had created a forked repo, but when creating a merge request it would select the upstream as the destination.

Basically I want to have a repo that's going to be public and other private repos that derive from that one that will be private as they contain private information for specific clients.

Answer (score 0):

Forks are for contributing back to upstream only.

Automatic reflection would be through [repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html).

But it is simpler to have your upstream repository as a remote, fetch from it whenever you want and work on local branches in your downstream repository.

Comment: Basically I want to have a repo that's going to be public and other private repos that derive from that one that will be private as they contain private information for specific clients. How would you go about this one?

Comment: @CCC It depends on the nature of the private informations. If they are limited to configurations, I would use one repository, with content filter driver (to generate the actual files needed by the project, with the right information in them), as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48449663/6309, with sensitive data coming from a Vault, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48728022/6309