# How to remove sensitive information before "git push"

Tags: git, push, commit, git-commit, git-push

My python application has database keys/api keys on source code.
Something like:

```
db_key    = XXXXXXXXXXXX
api_token = XXXXXXXXXXXX

...
```

I want to remove this keys automatically (Not the entire file) before commiting/pushing to git.
Also, I want to remove this from my previous commits (already pushed to github).
Is there any solutions?

Comment: put the keys in a config file and add it to `.gitignore`

Comment: I want to remove specific 'parts' of a file, not the entire file...

Comment: Post Edited - Added information about not removing entire file.

Comment: Try a smudge clean filter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909620/git-smudge-clean-filter-between-branches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing credentials/sensitive information in source code is a bad practice. It could be avoided by storing them in external location. Depending on requirements/security level external location could be:

- environment variable
- configuration file not stored in version control
- database
- dedicated system like Hashicorp's Vault

Regarding your other part of the question – removing already pushed credentials. First disable leaked credentials (there are bots looking for them, both from Github and malicious users).

When credentials are disabled you need to rewrite history. This could be done with `git rebase`. Please be informed that rewriting public history is considered a bad practice and should be avoided. I would rather disable credentials and add commits that adds modification described in first part of the answer.

Doing the change automatically is possible with using pre-commit hook on your side, but that is not the best idea. After that change `git status` will always show you that workspace differs from index.

Other option would be to use filters, but that sound like overengineering to me. With this you'll fix the problem, but not the root cause (storing credentials in plain text in source code).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is to put your keys in a separated file, then all you need to do is create a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and put this file there. Now you get the keys from reading this file.

If you don't want to use it as a separated file then you will need to remove it manually every time or write a script that does it (overhead and will be painful depending on the file).

For security reasons you should change both tokens since it is easy to get them from your git history, changing them will leave you with one less problem which is fixing the git history which has your tokens.