# React native project custom package name for different builds

Tags: git, react-native

I'm trying to manage my React Native app project (CRNA ejected) using different package names so I can release/test different flavors:

```
com.mydomain.internal
com.mydomain.alpha
com.mydomain.beta
```

Ideally, I want to develop & test `com.mydomain.internal` app package on my git master branch, and push the change to `alpha` branch (this branch should build `com.mydomain.alpha` package), and then push the change to `beta` branch where it should build `com.mydomain.beta` app package.

I want to avoid manually change the package names for every release because it touches a lot of files and could easily break things. I'm wondering if there's a good way to help me maintain/update multiple app flavors/versions like above. If icons can be changed too, please also point that out, so that I can create different icons for different flavors.

(I was thinking about config the manifests and read the package name from a static file, but doesn't seem to work)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution to this problem called `Build Varient` for Android. This article has well explained how to set it up: https://medium.com/@ywongcode/building-multiple-versions-of-a-react-native-app-4361252ddde5

Answer (score 0):

Consider that a script can determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

That means you could (using "config" here as a generic term, replace it by the right file to modify):

- version only a template file `config.tpl`
- version value files named after the branches: `config.dev`, `config.master`: since they are different, there is no merge issue when merging or switching branches.

Finally, you would register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script, associated to the template file (`config.tpl`), would generate (automatically on `git checkout`) the actual `config` file by looking values in the right `config.<branch>` value file.
The generated actual `config` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".