# Keeping package.json version intact during merge

Tags: gitlab

I need to find a way to keep 'version' intact in package.json of the 'dev' branch after merging 'feature' branch into 'dev'. I can't figure out the best way to do it. 
Can I do this just using .gitlab-ci.yml or a combination of bash script and gitlab yml. Note, 'feature' branch will always have differnt 'version' in package.json to the dev's package.json.

I tried using bash and assigning a variable to package.json 'version', then after merge updating package.json with pre-merge version. Doesn't seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to *not* version `package.json` (ignore it), but to *generate* it (with the right value in it.

The generation script can determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

That means you could:

- version only a template file `package.json.tpl`
- version value files named after the branches: `version.dev`, `version.feature`: since they are different, there is no merge issue when merging or switching branches.

Finally, you would register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script, associated to the template file (`package.json.tpl`), would generate (automatically on `git checkout`) the actual `package.json` file by looking values in the right `version.<branch>` value file.
The generated actual `package.json` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:
My script.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'Current gitlab user and email'

echo $GITLAB_USER_NAME
echo $GITLAB_USER_EMAIL

git config user.email $GITLAB_USER_EMAIL
git config user.name $GITLAB_USER_NAME
git fetch --all

git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

echo 'Getting version from package.json master'
git checkout origin/master -- package.json
VERSION_DEV=$(cat package.json \
| grep version \
| head -1 \
| awk -F: '{ print $2 }' \
| sed 's/[",]//g' \
| tr -d '[[:space:]]')
git status
git reset
git checkout .

echo $VERSION_DEV
echo 'replacing version in package.json'
sed -i 's/\"version\":.*/\"version\": "'$VERSION_DEV'",/g' "package.json"
git add .
git commit -m "package.json version preserved"

# Success
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Success in preserving package.json version"


echo 'Checking out master'
git checkout master

echo 'Merging into master'
git merge $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --no-ff --no-edit
git push --follow-tags origin  master
```

my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
job-merge:
  before_script:
    - git remote set-url origin https://oauth2:${CI_PUSH_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/mysername/myrepo.git
  script:
    - echo 'STARTING TO RUN SCRIPTS'
    - bash ./script.sh
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

CI_PUSH_TOKEN is a variable in CI/CD settings of the project that is personal access token with api scope.