# GIT environment path

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I am using Git for our code repository.
Each repo we got consist of `master`, `development` and `fix` branch.

The `master` we use that for our code that resides in production, while development is our report for our development changes.
My `prd` and `dev` site have different path.

How do you configure that in order to make every deployment to `prd` or `dev` seamless using different branch?
Right now, I have a path in my `packages.json`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to *not* version [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) (keep it private), but to *generate* it (with the right value in it).

The generation script will determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

That means you could:

- version only a template file `package.json.tpl`
- version value files named after the branches: `version.dev`, `version.master`: since they are different, there is no merge issue when merging or switching branches.

Finally, you would register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script, associated to the template file (`package.json.tpl`), would generate (automatically, on `git checkout`) the actual `package.json` file by looking values in the right `version.<branch>` value file.
The generated actual `package.json` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".

Comment: I have played around attributes. Do you have tutorial I can follow?

Comment: @Billy Mainly the link I mention at the end: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309