# How can I ignore the .env file in git?

Tags: git, gitignore

I made changes in my .env file and wrote after that in terminal `git status`:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .env
```

I would like that the changes in the .env file be igonored by git so I added this line in .gitignore:

```
/.env
```

Now when I write `git status` I get the result:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .env
    modified:   .gitignore
```

What can I do now? Why is gitignore not ignored?

Comment: gitignore only effects files that have not yet been commited. You can use `git rm --cached` to delete it but this will delete it for all users except yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git still shows files as modified after adding to .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750606/git-still-shows-files-as-modified-after-adding-to-gitignore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with a `git rm --cached .env` (which would enable to .gitignore to operate) is that, once committed and pushed, everybody lose the file on their next `git pull`.

If you need to have local `.env` settings (that should not be part of your Git repository), you can either:

- check if your .env comes with some kind of `#include` directive, which would allow you to include a second file .env.local (that you can add safely to your `.gitignore`)
- or setup a merge content driver, and version only `.env.tpl` (a template file), while ignoring `.env` itself (so using the `git rm --cached .env`, but with a git add `.env.tpl`)

The idea behind a [content filter driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter) is to generate automatically on `git checkout`/`git switch` the `.env` file, based on the `.env.tpl` template file and a local (and ignored) `.env.values` value file.
See "[Github private repo - manage packages for different environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016655/6309)" as an example of such an approach.