# How to have branch specific variables in GIT and python

Tags: python, git, merge, environment-variables, git-branch

I have 2 different branches, `master` and `test`. Those branches are exact replicas except for the database string which is different for master and test. Everytime I *merge* test to master, the database string in the master gets replaced by the test database string.

I have heard about using branch specific variables, so I don't need to worry about the database string getting changes on merge as .env variables will take care of it.

Please let me know how do I do that.

Comment: Where are your environment variables stored? You should be able to have separate files to store the environment variables for each branch.

Comment: i did not make env files yet. @adamgy

Comment: This sounds like you don't need separate branches, but could read the database string from some environment specific configuration. This would avoid any merge problems.

Comment: How to I make env files and access thier value in code? Can you provide with an example?

Comment: `python-dotenv` is great for automatically setting env variables with a .env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as .env variables will take care of it.

You could generate the right .env file.
And rename the current `.env` into `.env.master` and `.env.test`

In each branch, you would then *generate* `.env`, with the right content in it, from one of those files, depending on the current execution environment.

The generation script will determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Finally, you would register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script, associated the `.env.branch` file, would generate (automatically, on `git checkout` or `git switch`) the actual `.env` file by looking values in the right `.env.branch` value file.
The generated actual `.env` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".