# How to make jenkins build status badge dynamically show the branch of the its file is in

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I'm not sure if the summary is clear on this. What I want to do is create a jenkins build status badge url that will somehow be able to figure out the Git branch it is on, and add the correct branch suffix to the url dynamically.

I want to do this so I can create a readme file that always shows the `master`, `develop`, and `<branch-i'm-looking-at>` jenkins builds of that repo, without having to manually update the badge for each branch.

I know how to create branch-specific build status badges. Jenkins automatically builds the markdown URL for you. For example one of mine for a`develop` branch looks like:

```
[![Build Status](https://jenkins.mycompany.com/path/to/build/develop/badge/icon?subject=develop)]
(https://jenkins.mycompany.com/path/to/build/develop/)
```

I can imagine it'd be something using the `${BRANCH_NAME}` jenkins env var, but i can't think of how to create it. I'm not experienced enough with git hooks or other scripting to even start to come up with a way to do it.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of creating a `README`, I would maintain 4 `README`s, one per branch, each one with their own *static* Jenkins URL, tailored to their own branch.

The `README` in the `develop` branch, for instance, would have the URL:

```
[![Build Status](https://jenkins.mycompany.com/path/to/build/develop/badge/icon?subject=develop)]
(https://jenkins.mycompany.com/path/to/build/develop/)
```

---

> Also, these being multibranch pipelines, the branches will come and go.

Then I would consider a content filter driver.

That means only *one* `README` file with a placeholder value in it.
("placeholder value": a string meant to be replaced. For instance: `@URL@`)

That allows you to *generate* the right `README` file locally, and to do so automatically on `git clone`/`git checkout`.

The generation script will:

- detect the current checked-out branch
- replace the placeholder value in `README` to generate the right `README`, with the proper "Build Status" URL

For that, do register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#filters_a)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script will generate (automatically, on `git checkout` or `git switch`) the actual `README` file as mentioned above.
That script can use:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

See a complete example at "[`git smudge`/`clean` filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".

I would also add a `clean` filter in order to restore the original README content (placeholder value), in order to not introduced (from a `git diff` perspective) any difference.

[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/clean.png]

So to recap:

- on `git checkout`/`restore`, the `smudge` script declared in the `.gitattributes` file is automatically activated, and replaces the placeholder value by the correct URL, with the branch name
- on `git diff`/`commit`, the `clean` script declared in the `.gitattributes` file is automatically activated, and replaces the generate URL by the original placeholder value.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don’t think this is an answer. As I state in the original question, I already know how to create branch-specific build status badges. Jenkins automatically builds the markdown URL for you. Maintaining multiple readmes is not a scalable solution. Also, these being multibranch pipelines, the branches will come and go. Only `develop` and `master` are static. I need a _dynamic_ solution.

Comment: @MaxCascone A dynamic solution? Sure thing. I have edited the answer to proposes a possible implementation.

Comment: Now THIS looks extremely interesting. Looking forward to trying it and will get back ASAP.

Comment: I finally read through this thoroughly, and I realize it's not the answer. And that's my fault for not explaining the issue correctly. What I need is, something that will show _in the GitHub web UI_ the branch name in the URL, without committing unique files per branch. Is that more clear?

Comment: @MaxCascone Clearer indeed, but not as easily achieved than creating a readme file (as mentioned in the original question). I don't have an immediate solution, but will keep looking.

Comment: ...sorry it took me a year to look this closely. I appreciate the quick response!