# how to maintain a production and development branches in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, development-environment, production

In my project i have this `constants.ts` file which stores my `API_URL`. I want to keep two API_URLs in my production(main) and development branches.

ex: development -> API_URL = 'http://localhost:4000'
main -> APIURL = 'https://backend.com'

but when I change the API_URL and commit when it comes to merging the main and the development branch it detects as a change. so if I merge it constant file in main branch will be also changes. How to ignore the changes of this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my project, I have this `constants.ts` file which stores my `API_URL`.

The idea would be to store two files:

- `constants.ts.main`
- `constants.ts.dev`

(I use [`main` instead of `master` here](https://github.com/github/renaming))

- keep `constants.ts` ignored from now on: `echo constants.ts>>.gitignore`.

That means generating the right `constants.ts` file locally: no complex merge involved when merging `dev` to `main`.

In each branch, you would then *generate* `constants.ts`, with the right content in it, from one of those files, depending on the current execution environment.

The generation script will determine the name of the checked out branch with:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Finally, you would register (in a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)) a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**.

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The `smudge` script, associated the `constants.ts` file, would generate (automatically, on `git checkout` or `git switch`) the actual `constants.ts` file by looking values in the right `constants.ts.<branch>` value file.
The generated actual `constants.ts` file remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).

See a complete example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".

Comment: this is really awesome Thank you!