# Quasar changes capacitor.config.json on dev server start

Tags: capacitor, quasar-framework, devserver

Running Quasar dev server in Capacitor mode with`quasar dev -m capacitor -T android` results in the dialog to choose external IP address:

```
? What external IP should Quasar use? 192.168.0.3
 App • Updated src-capacitor/package.json
 App • Updated capacitor.config.json
 App • Running "...\node_modules\@capacitor\cli\bin\capacitor sync android" in ...
```

The problem is that this updates `src-capacitor/capacitor.config.json` with local information that can be accidentally pushed, which is never desirable:

```
  "server": {
    "androidScheme": "https",
    "url": "http://192.168.0.3:9500" <-- this line is added
  }
```

Not to mention that most times it would be practical to skip this dialog, as the application runs locally and can safely use localhost instead of external IP.

As loosely described in [the documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-capacitor-apps/build-commands/#developing), this seems to be the expected behaviour but not desirable one.

How can updating `server.url` in capacitor.config.json be avoided?

Answer (score 5):

`quasar dev -m capacitor -T android` starts a web server and makes capacitor use that web server url for live reload.
That’s what the dev option is for, so you can’t change that behavior.
If you want to run your app without the live reload server you can use
`quasar build -m capacitor -T android` instead, that will remove the server url from the `capacitor.config.json`.

Comment: Nice, that seems simpler than my answer.

Comment: So server.url doesn't affect neither dev server nor a build in Quasar, correct?

Comment: If you (or quasar) set the server.url, the app will load from that url, it can be a local liver reload server url or a remote website. But if you set it manually it has to match a server already running, it won’t make any changes in quasar server.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that this updates `src-capacitor/capacitor.config.json` with local information that can be accidentally pushed, which is never desirable:

That is why your actual config files should remain private (not tracked by Git).
You should only track config file *values*, plus a config file template

```
  src-capacitor/capacitor.config.dev.json
  src-capacitor/capacitor.config.prod.json
  src-capacitor/capacitor.config.tpl.json
```

Then, you can use a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

The script generate the right `json` file by replacing placeholder values with the fixed value `"url": "http://192.168.0.3:9500"` each time you checkout a branch, when the smudge script detects a local development environment.

The generated actual `conf` remains ignored (by the `.gitignore`).
No synchronization issue during merges.

The smudge script selects the correct value file and *generates* the correct `json` based on the template the smudge script is applied to during a `git switch` (or old `git checkout`).

See a content driver setup example at "[git smudge/clean filter between branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909620/6309)".

Your `.gitattributes` would include `src-capacitor/capacitor.config.json filter=smudgeScript`

```bash
git config filter.smudgeScript.smudge /path/to/your/smudgeScript
git config filter.smudgeScript.clean "cat src-capacitor/capacitor.config.tpl.json"
```

With `smudgeScript` (here, I simulate the logic which detects you are in a "devServer" with a hypothetical `ENV` variable):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ENV=$(git branch --show-current)

if [[ "$ENV" == "development" ]]; then
  CONFIG_FILE="src-capacitor/capacitor.config.dev.json"
elif [[ "$ENV" == "production" ]]; then
  CONFIG_FILE="src-capacitor/capacitor.config.prod.json"
else
  # Default to development environment
  CONFIG_FILE="src-capacitor/capacitor.config.dev.json"
fi

cat $CONFIG_FILE
```

---

The alternative is to code that logic in the [`quasar.conf.js`](https://v1.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js)

```js
module.exports = function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
    // ...other configurations
    devServer: {
      public: 'http://localhost:8080',  // replace with your local development server address
    },
  }
}
```

That would set a static URL in your `quasar.conf.js`. Inside the devServer property, specify a public property with your desired URL. You need to add the logic which detects you are in a "devServer".

---

> Unfortunately, it appears that it's not possible to specify 127.0.0.1 for Capacitor in the config without modifying Quasar source code, even though it would be possible to make it work with Android Studio. Looks like specifying 192.168.xx.xx IP and discarding the changes from git is the way to go.

True, and using the first approach, where `src-capacitor/capacitor.config.json` is ignore, will allow you to specify what you need in it, without risking to add/commit/push said modification.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The last part isn't precise but a good starting point for the research. Unfortunately, it appears that it's not possible to specify 127.0.0.1 for Capacitor in the config without modifying Quasar source code, even though it would be possible to make it work with Android Studio. Looks like specifying 192.168... ip and discarding the changes from git is the way to go

Comment: @EstusFlask Good point. The first part of the answer should help with any modification to `src-capacitor/capacitor.config.json`

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood of Quasar/Vite/Capacitor setup, [`devServer.host` configuration option](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-file/#property-devserver) is compared against hardcoded set of addresses:

```
`'0.0.0.0', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1'`
```

In case a host is considered local (`0.0.0.0` by default), external IP dialog is triggered, otherwise `devServer.host` is used as is. The value is written to `capacitor.config.json` nonetheless.

It's likely possible to specify another loopback (`127.0.0.2`) in `devServer.host` to pass this check and keep a usable default configuration for iOS-only project. It won't be available in Android Studio emulator as [it aliases `127.0.0.1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806384/3731501) that falls under the restriction.

A reasonable approach would be pass locally configured external IP to `quasar.config.json` with `dotenv` and discard the changes in `capacitor.config.json` by means of Git.