# Tell git to always pull the remote version of a file in case of conflict

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

I want to tell git that in case of conflict on a merge on a specific file he has to always use the remote version of the file.

The only thing I found was how to always keep the local version of the file:
[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s)
and [.gitattributes & individual merge strategy for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465122/gitattributes-individual-merge-strategy-for-a-file)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge -X theirs`

See more details about the "theirs" merge strategy option:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html